# How can I select the database's data using whereBetween() with especific time(hours, minutes)?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to select all day sales stored in a database but the problem is that the workday starts at 6PM and ends at 5AM. For example: Friday from 6:00 P.M to 5:00 A.M on Saturday.

How can I solve this problem using whereBetween() or is there another solution?

The code below is the old version, when the work day started and ended the same day.

SalesController php

```
$sales_day = DB::table('sales')->where('active',1)->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereTime()` function to filter a range of time.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks Rubys... I used whereBetwee() and whereTime().

Answer (score 0):

Following Rubys' suggestion above I found this solution:

```
$sales_day = DB::table('sales')->where('active',1)
            ->whereBetween('created_at',[
                Carbon::today()->toDateString(),//first day
                Carbon::today()->addDays(1)->toDateString()//second day
            ])
            ->whereTime('created_at','>=','12:00:00')//12:00 as 23:59
            ->whereTime('created_at','<=','5:00:00')//00:00 as 05:00
            ->orderBy('id','desc')
            ->paginate(15);
```